# Trouble with this simple stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
create procedure sp_DescuentoCategoriaInvierno
as
declare @IDProductoOfertado int, @ProductoNombre nvarchar(256), @CategoriaNombre nvarchar(256), @SubcategoriaNombre nvarchar(256), @Precio float

declare cursorProducto cursor for
select o.IDProducto, p.Nombre, c.Nombre, s.Nombre, o.Precio from OfertaProducto as o
inner join Producto as p on o.IDProducto = p.ID
inner join Subcategoria as s on p.IDSubcategoria = s.ID
inner join Categoria as c on s.IDCategoria = c.ID
order by p.Nombre

open cursorProducto
    fetch next from cursorProducto into @IDProductoOfertado, @ProductoNombre, @CategoriaNombre, @SubcategoriaNombre, @Precio
    while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        begin
            if(@CategoriaNombre='Invierno')
            begin           
                select @Precio --TROUBLE IS HERE. 
                from OfertaProducto --WHAT SHOULD I DO?
                update OfertaProducto set Precio = @Precio * 0.5                
            end
            fetch next from cursorProducto into @IDProductoOfertado, @ProductoNombre, @CategoriaNombre, @SubcategoriaNombre, @Precio
        end

close cursorProducto
deallocate cursorProducto
```

This one is simple enough, I'm just trying to have every OferredProduct in my dabase that has a Category of 'invierno' have a reduced price:

Here's the model:

[image]

So what I'd like it to iterate through each OfferedProduct, if it has a category of 'Invierno' reduce the price of it to 50%. I'm missing something small I'm sure. :P

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Jeff said before, you don't need a cursor for this, it would be better just an UPDATE statement for this. Try something like this:

```
UPDATE o
SET o.Precio = o.Precio * 0.5
from OfertaProducto as o
inner join Producto as p on o.IDProducto = p.ID
inner join Subcategoria as s on p.IDSubcategoria = s.ID
inner join Categoria as c on s.IDCategoria = c.ID
WHERE c.Nombre = 'Invierno'
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand this:

```
select @Precio 
from OfertaProducto 
update OfertaProducto set Precio = @Precio * 0.5
```

`@Precio` is already selected through the cursor, so why do you select it again. And you also need to give an id in the update statement. Otherwise all rows wlil be updated. I think this would do it:

```
update OfertaProducto set Precio = @Precio * 0.5 where IDProducto = @IDProductoOfertado
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the select statement but you do need a where clause on your update statement:

```
update OfertaProducto set Precio = @Precio * 0.5
where IDProducto=@IDProductoOfertado
```

Note that this could be accomplished better with a single UPDATE statement acting on the entire set at once

Comment: In your example, is IDProducto the foreign key in my far right table?

Comment: IDProducto is the field in the OfertaProducto table. @IDProductOfertado is the variable you've already defined in your stored procedure and that is being used in the FETCH statement for the cursor.